# Find the limit $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{3^k}\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{3^k}\right)\right)$$

I know that I can rewrite it as:
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{9}+\frac{3}{27}+...+\frac{n}{3^n}=\frac{3^{n-1}+2\cdot 3^{n-2}+...+n}{3^n}$$ How would I take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Let $|x|<1$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}\implies \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\underset{\text{why ?}}{=}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x^k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}.$$

Finally, you get that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k=x\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}=x\cdot \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right). $$

Answer (score 1):

Your inner formula is the sum $S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^nnx^n$ (or, if you prefer, $\sum_{k=0}^nnx^n$ - the latter is the same value since it just adds a zero term, but can be easier to work with) evaluated at $x=\frac13$. Working by analogy with a similar approach for the geometric series, take a look at $(x-1)S_n(x)$ — you should be able to simplify a bunch of terms and be left with a couple of 'boundary' terms plus a sum that should look familiar.